# summary table with total whilst controlling for value on one variable?

Tags: r

I've used function summary(data[data$var1==5,]) to get a summary of observations while controlling var1 at 5 (or whatever).

However, I also need a total for a particular var2 as well, and I'm unsure how to go about coding that in here whilst keeping the variable that I want controlled at 5 (or 1, or whatever).

I'm quite happy writing a second line looking for the total of var2 whilst controlling var1.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why not use `&`, as in `summary(data[data$var1==5 & data$var2==1,])`? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I think so.  I have a summary of my dataset from the function I put up there summary(data[data$var1==5,])

I want to see totals of other variables as well, but making sure that only the totals when var=x (in the case above it is 5).  The var1 in my case is separate experiments, so I only want means and totals etc for those experiments.  The summary table, annoyingly, doesn't have totals in it, so basically I'm just looking to get a total function in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
sum(data[data$var1==5,]$var2)
```

or (without the comma)

```
sum(data$var2[data$var1==5])
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I'm new to this so it's taking me a little time to get my head around the commands.  I'm getting there, thanks ever so much.

Comment: If Henry's answer resolved your question, please *accept* it by clicking the check mark beneath the vote total. You may also want to *upvote* it, now that you have >15 rep. You may want to consider accepting answer to your other questions as well. This is a polite way of acknowledging people's help.

Comment: @killahtron Notifying you of gung's comment.

Comment: @gung You need to @-tag OP in order for the notification to show up in their inbox.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @BlueMagister. I was under the impression that the OP & the answerer were always notified; perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: @gung Since you replied on Henry's answer, Henry gets the automatic reply and no one else. Here's a link to [how comment @-replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).